# JMX Bean for few types of Requests

Tags: java, performance, jmx, jconsole

I want to show performance statistics for particular request type. When Controller class gets the HTTP Request from browser, it then marshals request xml in to a request object. From request object I can get request type.
Is it possible to inject JMX MBeans for particular request type and broadcast it to JConsole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to inject JMX MBeans for particular request type and broadcast it to JConsole?

Jconsole does polling of statistics and you can't "broadcast" a request type that you define since that class won't be in the Jconsole jar.

What you can do is keep a count of the request types in a map and then return a `String[]` of `type -> count` string output if you like.  Something like:

```
public String[] getResultTypeCount() {
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : typeMap.entrySet()) {
         list.add(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());
     }
     return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

You might want to look into [JMX notifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/notifs/).

Comment: Can I register Request class to JConsole?

Comment: No @HimanshuYadav.  You have to use classes that are built into the JDK.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. I can create a JMX Bean for the request object. Is it possible to register JMX Bean for particular request types?

Comment: Yes, sure @HimanshuYadav. You can call `mbeanExporter.registerManagedResource(object, name);` anytime you want to register on demand objects for a particular request type.

Comment: You might consider using my SimpleJMX library which makes it pretty easy: http://256.com/sources/simplejmx/

Comment: Great! And It will give me what I am expecting. Right? Or would it behave in a different way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28764/discussion-between-gray-and-himanshu-yadav)